# If this value is found in a range, then use the value next to the range result

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

Hopefully an easy solution:

Look for value of C2 in Column range N3:N300. If found, then put value of P* into D2.

Example:

C2 = "Cat"

Search N3:N300 for "Cat"

Finds N176 = "Cat"

Then makes D2 = value of P176, in this case, "feline"

Is there Excel formula to do this?

Comment: [`Vlookup`](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function) will be your best friend

Comment: Someone suggested this and it worked: =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(O3,B:B,0))

Comment: Vlookup does exactly what you wanted.. It searches for a match and outputs the value of the cell next to it. I mean, why did you make things harder?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a VLookup function.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1